# Refactoring in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have single C file open in VS Code:

```
struct Sales{
   int total_and_vat;
   int total;
};

struct AllSales {
   struct Sales negative;
   struct Sales positive;
};
```

I have **C/C++** and **C/C++ Extension Pack**  extensions in my VS Code.

Now I would like to rename type Sales to MySales. How to make this in VS Code? I don't need just simple text replace, I need source file analysis. How to make refactoring in VS Code?

Comment: I don't know about the stock Microsoft C++ extension, but Clangd (which I like more) can rename symbols with F2, I believe.

Comment: Usually it's F2. Place the cursor on 'Sales', press F2, and you should get a text input with 'Sales' prefilled. Change to 'MySales' and press Enter. The extension should now change the name everywhere in the project.

Comment: Solution given by md2perpe works for me. Thanks md2perpe !

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the 'Sales' method.

You will then be presented with an option to 'Change All Occurrences'

(This can also be achieved by the shortcut F2)

You can now change the name of your method to 'MySales' by simply replacing the highlighted text.

This will change / refractor all occurrences and references to the method to 'MySales'